# Problems opening xyz.html from root of sdcard using webviewer component

Tags: android, html, filepath, android-sdcard, app-inventor

I have created an app which, on startup downloads a file (**xyz.html**) into the root of the sdcard.

I tried using following file paths:

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/xyz.html -> works in Google chrome on Nexus 4

file://mnt/sdcard/xyz.html

file://xyz.html

file:///android_asset/xyz.html -> did not work
```

but all that happens is "webpage not available".
Need help.
What are the correct file-path formats for viewing/accessing files from the sdcard, the root of sdcard?

**Blocks:**

```
screen1.initialize
```

if else test- global d = empty?
then
web1.goToUrl>dropbox.com/..... (file gets downloaded)
web1.GET
else
webviewer1.goToUrl>file:///mnt/sdcard/xyz.html
.w2
.w3
.w4
webviewer5.goToUrl>file///mnt..

```
web1.gotFile
```

webviewer1.goToUrl...(same as above)

```
btnShow.clicked
```

set webviewer1,2,3,4,5.visible to TRUE

```
btnHide.clicked
```

set webviewer1,2..5.visible to FALSE
tinydb1.storeValue [tag: title] [value to store: webviewer1.CurrentPageTitle]
set label1.text to> tinydb1.getValue [tag: title]

[image: screen1.initialize block]

[image: web1.gotfile block]

Comment: the filepath file:///mnt/sdcard/xyz.html displays page if opened in chrome browser (Nexus 4)

Comment: Your filepath `file:///mnt/sdcard/xyz.html` is correct. Post the relevant parts of your blocks.

Comment: so there are 5 webviewer showing the same html file? Try to get runing one webviewer first and modify in Web1.GotFile: `mapViewer1.GoToUrl=(value)map`. The (value)map block you will find in your definitions

Comment: Failure.. url as direct value opens **/storgae.../map.html** and the webpage isnt available in that case.
in second case, after `file://` _join text_ `value` doesnt open anything. remains blank.
and definitely this is not a connection prob as i had made sure about 3g connection.

Comment: the (value)map variable is *only* avaiable in the *Web1.GotFile* event and provides the path to your downloaded html file...

Comment: So? I'm defining "go to URL" only after got file event is triggered.. Don't notice the problem or fault you're trying to mention

Comment: I do not see any error... I'm just trying to find a working solution for you... Probably the file is not there where you expect it to be?

Comment: it is. i can see it from file explorer

Comment: try it on another device to avoid device specific problems

Answer (score 0):

If your sdcard is mounted at `/mnt/sdcard` then `file:///mnt/sdcard/xyz.html` is correct. However many devices mount the card(external hardware sdcard) to either extsd or external_sd so then the paths change to    `file:///mnt/extsd/xyz.html` / `file:///mnt/external_sd/xyz.html` . These devices consider the onboard storage as `/mnt/sdcard/`. Again these paths might have vendor specific names, but these are what I've seen so far.  Check where your sdcard is mounted and post more info

Comment: you said `the filepath file:///mnt/sdcard/xyz.html displays page if opened in chrome browser`, which means, that path is correct... there probably is an error in how you put together your blocks... therefore without posting your blocks it is not possible to provide more help without guessing, e.g. are you using an external anchor, e.g. `file:///mnt/sdcard/xyz.html#myAnchor`? This will not work for Android 3.x/4.x devices.